# Why can't I remarry after my husband died?

Tags: the-sims-2

In The Sims 2 Double Deluxe, my husband just died.

I'm trying to marry another Sim, but it won't let me. Do I need to get a divorce or something?

I have tried everything but nothing is working and I can't find anyone who has had the some problem.

Comment: I've never played, but is your Sim mourning the loss or something? Perhaps they want to "let the sheets cool down" before inviting someone else in.

Answer (score 1):

Is the tombstone still on the lot? If the stone's still on the lot, your Sim will still be grieving.

A simple solution: move the stone or delete it.

:) hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the tombstone, you should either place it in your sim's inv
or delete it if it is not that it could be a bug so you should browse for bugfixes, backup your save onto your desktop then delete the one in game then place the original save file back into the game files then open the game again.

But of course it could always be due to the fact of your sim mourning. This may take 2 days to 1 week so wait then before doing anything.